# Change the default value of date in C# just by using the validation controls?

Tags: c#, validation, date

Basically, this is my code to enter the date of birth.

```
<asp:TextBox Width="208px" ID="txtDOB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqDOB" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDOB" ErrorMessage="Cannot be blank" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:CompareValidator ErrorMessage="(MM/DD/YYYY)" Display="Dynamic" ID="valcDate" ControlToValidate="txtDOB" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" runat="server"> </asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="valrDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDOB" MinimumValue="01/01/1800" MaximumValue="01/01/2100" Type="Date" text="Invalid Date" Display="Dynamic"/> </asp:RangeValidator>
```

So now I want to override the basic format from `mm-dd-yyyy` to `dd-mm-yyyy`. Is there any basic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c# you can customise the format like this :-

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));
```

Comment: but for this i'll have to manipulate the in the normal code. isn't there a way from the validation control format in the properties when you're basically assigning it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the validator controls are culture aware, so the easiest solution is to set an appropriate culture (e.g. en-GB).  An easy way to do this is:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <globalization culture="en-GB" />
    ...
<system.web>
```

Of course your error message needs to be adapted to the chosen culture too.  For example you might want to set the error message to:

```
"(" + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToUpper() + ")"
```